# Loop through grouped data and perform

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

Suppose I have the following example:

My original dataset includes the vars from `VisitLink` to `Dis 3`. I want to make a new var `new` so that when I group the data by `Patient`,look back into 20 days prior to the visit of that patient, check if `Dis1` is true in any of those visits that time. My desired `new` would be:

I made several attempts but they all ignore the grouping.

```
Patient DaysToEvent  Dis1  Dis2  Dis3   new
      1         130  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
      1         135 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
      2         456  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
      2         500 FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE
      2         550  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
      2         560 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
      3         200 FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE
      3         400  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
      3         410 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
      3         510 FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE
      4           1  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
      4          20 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
      4         110 FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: your provided column `new` includes your expected output? If so, I have difficulties to understand what you want.

Comment: @Jimbou `new` is the desired output I would like. I just made up the example. In fact I'm trying to do this for 3 million records so I can't manually do it

Comment: @raistlin can you explain your question? To clarify, I want idea for code to produce the `new` function. Let me explain it further, for patient #1, even though he doesn't get diagnosed for the first disease, within 20 days before that visit, he was diagnosed positive for that disease in an earlier event, that's why it's TRUE

Comment: Have added a second solution.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Create a function `gen_new` which for each patient fills in the missing day numbers giving `m`.  Then it uses `rollapplyr` with `any(..., na.rm = TRUE)` to find if any of the trailing 20 or fewer elements are TRUE and then, using `window`, subsets the result back to just the days that were present. To apply it to all patients use `ave`.  `ave` will coerce the logicals produced by `gen_new` to 0/1 so compare its output to 1 to convert back to logical.

```
library(zoo)

n <- nrow(DF)

gen_new <- function(ix) with(DF[ix, ], {
  rng <- range(DaysToEvent)
  m <- merge(zoo(Dis1, DaysToEvent), zoo(, seq(rng[1], rng[2])))
  window(rollapplyr(m, 20, any, na.rm = TRUE, partial = TRUE), DaysToEvent)
})

DF <- transform(DF, new2 = ave(1:n, Patient, FUN = gen_new) == 1)

# check that new and new2 are the same
identical(DF$new, DF$new2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)**  This one avoids the merge in (1) and so may be faster.  It defines a function `Any` that takes a logical zoo object and determines if there are any TRUE elements within 20 of the end.  Then it defines `gen_new` to `rollapplyr` it over a single person.  Finally it uses `ave` to apply that to each person.

```
library(zoo)

n <- nrow(DF)

Any <- function(x) any(x[time(x) > end(x) - 20], na.rm = TRUE)

gen_new <- function(ix) with(DF[ix, ], {
  z <- zoo(Dis1, DaysToEvent)
  rollapplyr(z, 20, Any, coredata = FALSE, partial = TRUE)
})

DF <- transform(DF, new2 = ave(1:n, Patient, FUN = gen_new) == 1)

# check that new and new2 are the same
identical(DF$new, DF$new2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**Note:** The input data `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "Patient DaysToEvent  Dis1  Dis2  Dis3   new
      1         130  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
      1         135 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
      2         456  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
      2         500 FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE
      2         550  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
      2         560 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
      3         200 FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE
      3         400  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
      3         410 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
      3         510 FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE
      4           1  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
      4          20 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
      4         110 FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I learned about zoo function in your comment which is very interesting. However, there is a simpler way to do it, I used to come up with it once but then get stuck in getting it back now. Your method while works but takes a long running time and I'm going to do this process for 3 million observations without a supercomputer

Answer (score 0):

I'm open to more efficient suggestion but here is the solution just using `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

group_by(mydata,Patient) %>% 
    do(new = sapply(.$DaysToEvent,function(x)
        {
            any(.$Dis1*between(.$DaysToEvent,x-20,x))
        }
    ) %>% 
    unnest()
```

Comment: When I run this on the DF in the Note in my answer it fails with an error.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck interesting. which error is it? And make sure you load in library tidyr . If you find this pose helpful, please give a positive vote. I'm trying to build SO "reputation"

Comment: Start a new R session, copy and paste the code in the Note at the end of my answer, enter the line `mydata <- DF` and then copy and paste your code and you will see the error.

Comment: I followed your instructions and have no problems

Comment: I am using  dplyr_0.7.1 and tidyr_0.6.3 on R 3.4.0 patched (Windows).  The error message I get is: *Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `new` must be length 1 (the group size), not 2*

Comment: I'm using R 3.3 and dplyr 0.5 but I think the difference in version should not be the reason.

Also, another way you can try:
`group_by(DF,Patient) %>% 
  mutate(new = map_lgl(DaysToEvent,.f = function(x){any(.$Dis1*between(.$DaysToEvent,x-20,x))}))`